# How to change the message in a Python AssertionError?

Tags: python, exception, assertions, nose

I'm writing per the following, in which I try to produce a decent error message when comparing two multiline blocks of Unicode text. The interior method that does the comparison raises an assertion, but the default explanation is useless to me

I need to add something to code such as this below:

```
def assert_long_strings_equal(one, other):
    lines_one = one.splitlines()
    lines_other = other.splitlines()
    for line1, line2 in zip(lines_one, lines_other):
        try:
            my_assert_equal(line1, line2)
        except AssertionError, error:
            # Add some information to the printed result of error??!
            raise
```

I cannot figure out how to change the printed error message in the assertionerror I catch. I always get `AssertionError: u'something' != 'something else'`, which only shows the first line of the output.

**How can I change the assertion message to print out whatever I want?**

If it's relevant, I am using `nose` to run the test.

Comment: Just to clarify, I realize that the catching of an Assertion error is strange. It just so happens that `my_assert_equal` is kind of deep and I don't want to mess with it.

Comment: Just to point out, you should have `except` not `catch`. Though I'm sure that's just a typo :p

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Use `e.args`, `e.message` is deprecated.

```
try:
    assert False, "Hello!"
except AssertionError as e:
    e.args += ('some other', 'important', 'information', 42)
    raise
```

This preserves the original traceback. Its last part then looks like this:

```
AssertionError: ('Hello!', 'some other', 'important', 'information', 42)
```

Works in both Python 2.7 and Python 3.

Comment: This just raises a type error when I try it on 2.7.

Comment: Which type of error? I was using 2.7 when writing the answer.

Comment: @philologon I just tried the solution (exact copy-paste of my answer) in both Python 2.7.10 and Python 3.5.1 and it works as expected. My answer has been downvoted, but I see no reason why.

Comment: @Honza Javorek Nice solution, but may be there is a on-liner with some library?

Comment: @matanster unlike print, assert is still a statement in the Python 3 https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-assert-statement

Answer (score 143):

```
assert expression, info
```

For instance,

```
>>> assert False, "Oopsie"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AssertionError: Oopsie
```

---

From the [docs](http://docs.python.org/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-assert-statementtrace.):

> Assert statements are a convenient way
>   to insert debugging assertions into a
>   program:
>
> ```
> assert_stmt ::=  "assert" expression
> ["," expression]
> ```
>
> The simple form,
>   `assert expression`, is equivalent to
>
> ```
> if __debug__:
>     if not expression:
>         raise AssertionError
> ```
>
> The extended form
>
> ```
> assert expression1, expression2
> ```
>
> is equivalent to
>
> ```
> if __debug__:
>     if not expression1:
>         raise AssertionError(expression2)
> ```
>
> These equivalences assume that
>   `__debug__` and `AssertionError` refer to the built-in variables with those
>   names. In the current implementation,
>   the built-in variable `__debug__` is
>   True under normal circumstances, False
>   when optimization is requested
>   (command line option -O). The current
>   code generator emits no code for an
>   assert statement when optimization is
>   requested at compile time. Note that
>   it is unnecessary to include the
>   source code for the expression that
>   failed in the error message; it will
>   be displayed as part of the stack
>   trace.

Comment: Note that you can also embed newlines in the `info` string expression to make them look nice when displayed.

Comment: Also note that you can add additional information to the string expression by using Python's string interpolation and newer string formating operations.

Comment: Raising an exception in general is not a problem. It's catching, modifying, and re-raising an expression, that I asked.

Comment: @Andres -- you should edit the question to say that explicitly... I don't interpret the question as saying that.

Comment: Smacks forehead.  Now it's clear why `assert(condition, message)` breaks with an always-true warning:  assert is an operator not a function, and so that statement tests a tuple.  Instead `assert condition message`

Answer (score 6):

You want to take the caught exception, convert it to a string, combine it with some additional string info, and raise a new exception.

```
x = 3
y = 5
try:
    assert( x == y )
except AssertionError, e:
    raise( AssertionError( "Additional info. %s"%e ) )
```

Comment: I didn't see any of the posted answers offer the general solution of how to add information to an exception and re-raise with both the original and additional information, which I thought was what the OP was asking.

Comment: Russel is right, this is the sort of thing I was looking for.

Answer (score 4):

You can pass the desired message when creating the exception.

```
raise AssertionError(line1 + ' != ' + line2)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: That's not what the OP means; `AssertionError` is (generally) raised by the `assert` statement.

Comment: I'm not sure... but if wrapped with an `if` statement  in place of using `assert` it might be acceptable. That way you could use an `if else` block and fallback on an AssertionError with a custom message.